How do I recover save progress on my games after resetting my iPad?
I reset my iPad, and it resulted in me losing all my save progress on the games Plants vs. Zombies 2 and Pokémon GO. I was hoping it would resolve itself automatically over time, but it hasn't.
Is there a way to recover my save progress on these games after resetting my iPad?

It depends.
Does the app save data to the cloud, in which case you provided the game with a login or it asked to use your Apple ID? In this case, log in to that account in the game.
If the data is only on the iPad, then by asking the iPad to reset, you explicitly asked for all the data to be deleted and lost forever. The only way is to restore the data from a backup.
